# App engine -- when to use memcache vs search index (and search API)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am interested in adding a spell checker to my app -- I'm planning on using difflib with a custom word list that's ~147kB large (13,025 words).

When testing user queries against this list, would it make more sense to:

1. load the dictionary into memcache (I guess from the datastore?) and keep it in memcache or
2. build an index for the Search API and pass in the user query against it there

I guess what I'm asking is which is faster: memcache or a search index?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Memcache is definitely faster.

Another important consideration is cost. Memcache API calls are free, while Search API calls have their own [quota and pricing](https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing).

By the way, you may store your library as a static file, because it's small and it does not change. There is no need to store it in the Datastore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply -- I was under the impression that we can't access the file system in GAE. Is there a way to access local static files from app engine scripts?

Comment: You cannot write to the files, but you can read static files.

Answer (score 1):

Memcache is faster however you need to consider the following.

1. it is not reliable, at any moment entities can be purged. So your code needs a fallback for non cached data
2. You can only fetch by key, so as you said you would need to store whole dictionaries in memcache objects.
3. Each memcache entity can only store 1MB. If you dictionary is larger you would have to span multiple entities. Ok not relevant in your case.

There are some other alternatives. How often will the dictionary be updated ?

Here is one alternate strategy.

You could store it in the filesystem (requires app updates) or GCS if you want to update the dictionary outside of app updates.  Then you can load the dictionary in each instance into memory at startup or on first request and cache it at the running instance level, then you won't have any round trips to services adding latencies. This will also be simpler code wise (ie no fallbacks if not in memcache etc)

Here is an example. In this case the code lives in a module, which is imported as required. I am using a yaml file for additional configuration, it could just as easily json load a dictionary, or you could define a python dictionary in the module.

```
_modsettings = {}

def loadSettings(settings='settings.yaml'):

    x= _modsettings
    if not x:
        try:
            _modsettings.update(load(open(settings,'r').read()))
        except IOError:
            pass

    return _modsettings

settings = loadSettings()
```

Then whenever I want the settings dictionary my code just refers to `mymodule.settings`.
By importing this module during a warmup request you won't get a race condition, or have to import/parse the dictionary during a user facing request.  You can put in more error traps as appropriate ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the reply -- I followed what you said except for this: "cache it at the running instance level"? Is this a cache that's separate from memcache I'm assuming? If this is a separate cache, do you know of a tutorial for accessing/manipulating it? Thanks.

Comment: If you load the dictionary into memory, you can assign it to a module level variable and then any request can access it.  It is effectively shared, so you would not want to update it in any way when running.

Comment: Thanks -- do you know how I can load the file from the file system (i.e. not GCS)? I can't do something like open('dictionary.txt','r'), can I?

Edit: I guess I could just put the dictionary into a *.py file and import it, right? Imported modules remain in memory I think..

Comment: Memcache and instance memory are not either/or. When an instance starts up, it can first check if the dictionary is already in Memcache. If it is, assign it to a variable and keep using it - no need to call Memcache. If not, read it and put it in Memcache, so that other instances can skip the reading step.

Comment: Though for such a small file, I believe you will find that reading from the filesystem will be faster than memcache.  Try both and measure the time.  something will need to parse the file and reconstruct the in memory dictionary or list.  protorpc doesn't appear to be super fast especially for large structures.